# Set pidgin settings to another folder

Tags: pidgin, portable-apps

As default on Windows 7 Pidgin sets its message logs and account settings to the folder

```
%AppData%\.purple
```

How do I move that folder to another location on my drive D:/ ?

I thought about using a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link), but I'm not sure if that works on different drives too. Maybe there is an easier solution by changing some registry settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the link for pidgin (the one in the start menu and desktop),
 
click Properties and in the Target: line change.

```
"C:\Program Files\Pidgin\pidgin.exe"
```

to

```
"C:\Program Files\Pidgin\pidgin.exe" --config="D:\SomeDir\.pidgin"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the `PURPLEHOME` environment variable to set a new location for the folder.

See: https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#Whereismy.purpledirectory